# Creating/Using Files with Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am trying to make something that would generate several random files and based on those files it determines the outcome of what happens (text based adventure game) and yes I want to use files due to the fact the game is supposed to be 'hack-able/mod-able.' For some reason trying to create the files in another directory gives me the error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file0599265.txt'

```
import os
import os.path
import random as rand
os.chdir("C:\Program Files (x86)\File Stuff")
f = open('file' + str(rand.randint(1,1000000)) + '.txt', 'w')
f.write('Test')
f.close
```

What must I do so that it will create that file? I really cannot nail the who change directory thing to make it where I want, but I will stick for this for now (The "C:\Program Files (x86)\File Stuff" was only made for testing purposes).

Comment: I can't duplicate - it works for me.

Comment: Make sure you escape your backslashes `os.chdir("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\File Stuff")`. This won't matter in this particular case since `\P` and `\F` are not valid escape sequences, but in general it can cause problems. Also, does this directory exist?

Comment: try to run your code for any other test directory outside of C:

Comment: One additional thing: you should have `f.close()` instead of `f.close`.

Comment: The directory does exist yes Michael Mior

Comment: The error message doesn't include the path. Are you absolutely certain that this exact program gives you this exact error?

Comment: alDiablo when I did it in a desktop file, I recieve the error "(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated\UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Bryan Oakley Yes, I am certain Python Idle gives me that error.

Comment: This code can't possibly give the error you say it does, if for no other reason than you're not importing `random`. Please provide _actual_ code that causes the _actual_ error. Code that is "like" your real code isn't useful unless it produces the same results as your real code.

Comment: Bryan Oakley I did provide actual code from my work, and my problem was already solved. I did import random, I just did add the fact that import the things I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4 issues:

1. You aren't importing `random` which will cuase errors
2. You should use the `with` keyword as it is pretty standard to use in this situation
3. You **must** have the directory `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\File Stuff` already created.
4. You need to change the `\`'s to `\\`'s.  `\` is an escape character, so if you don't escape the escape, then it can run into conflicts (i.e. `\n`).

Without further ado, here's the new code:

```
import os, os.path, random
os.chdir("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\File Stuff")
with open('file' + str(random.randint(1,1000000)) + '.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Test')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the file where you are sure to have write permission, such as in a subfolder of your home: `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME`.

I had no problem running your code, outside of `C:\Program Files (x86)\`

Comment: Already tried that, still didn't work. When I ran it from a file on my desktop it didn't work either.